# using “findFiles” in a Jenkinsfile with pattern matching more then one file by suffix , using glob ( ant glob)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

i try to capture 2 file types using ant glob and   “findFiles” in a Jenkinsfile
in my dir i have :

```
xxx.ipa
foo.plist
```

when i do :

```
files = findFiles(glob: '**/*.[ipa|plist]') 
or 
files = findFiles(glob: '**/*.ipa|*.plist')
```

I'm getting none, but when i do :

```
files = findFiles(glob: '**/*.ipa')
```

I do getting the xxx.ipa file .

im using jenkins findfiles which using ant glob to capture files by pattern
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `glob` is not a regex but [Ant Style pattern](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns).
So you either have to capture files separately or you could use a shell script with `grep` or `find` instead, e.g.:

```
def files = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'find . -name "*.ipa" -o -name "*.plist"')
```

Comment: @user63898 have you figured out how to do this?